# Rename [artemis] → [artemis-spaceship-bridge-simulator]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

The tags for [*Artemis: Spaceship Bridge Simulator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artemis:_Spaceship_Bridge_Simulator) can be expanded as follows, thanks to the 35 character tag limit.

- [artemis](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artemis) → [artemis-spaceship-bridge-simulator](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artemis-spaceship-bridge-simulator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Done:**

[artemis](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artemis) → [artemis-spaceship-bridge-simulator](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artemis-spaceship-bridge-simulator)